# would like not clickable/highlighted icons in listWidget

Tags: python, qlistwidget, pyside2

I have  QListWidget in Pyside2 that has icons populating it. I dont like the icons taking on a shaded grey look when the mouse clicks them. Is there a way to disable this action? I will include a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a delegate that disables the `QStyle::State_Selected` flag:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class StyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected
        super(StyledItemDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    delegate = StyledItemDelegate(w) # <---
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)      # <---
    w.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
    w.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
    w.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)

    for _ in range(20):
        it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        it.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("light.png"))
        w.addItem(it)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another option is to disable the `Qt::ItemIsSelectable` flag of the QListWidgetItem:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    w.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
    w.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
    w.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)

    for i in range(20):
        it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(str(i))
        it.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("light.png"))
        it.setFlags(it.flags() &~ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable) # <---
        w.addItem(it)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```